Minimal API Swagger doc keeps returning 404 when published to IIS
I have an ASP.NET Core 6.0 Minimal API. When I run it in IIS Express from VS, Swagger works just fine, but I want to publish it to IIS on my device so I don't always have to run it from VS.
Problem is, I can't get the Swagger doc to generate - I keep getting a 404. Here is my Program.cs:
var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
                      });
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
});
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDataAccess, DataAccess>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IExperienceService, ExperienceService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IExperienceData, ExperienceData>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUnitService, UnitService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUnitData, UnitData>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICategoryService, CategoryService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICategoryData, CategoryData>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILocationService, LocationService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILocationData, LocationData>();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
    options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

app.UseAuthorization();

app.ConfigureExperiences();
app.ConfigureUnits();
app.ConfigureCategories();
app.ConfigureLocations();

app.Run();

I downloaded the Hosting Bundle, installed it, restarted my device.
In IIS, I set it up to run on Port 80 over http. I set the physical path to .../Debug/net6.0. I gave IIS_IUSRS full permissions over the folder. There are firewall rules for allowing inbound traffic on port 80.
I also tried building the app with release config and running it out of the Release folder with the same result.
I just keep getting 404 when navigating to http://localhost/swagger/v1/swagger.json. Looking for ideas on what the issue could be. Thanks!

The current code seems to be fine. You need to share the complete Program.cs file so that we can further check the problem.

I updated it with the full Program.cs file. Thanks for taking a look!

So, I solved this question by building the application using dotnet publish. I thought running dotnet build -c Release was sufficient, but apparently there is some vagary between what these actually do that affects how Swagger works. I don't have a deep understanding (yet), but if I find out more, I will update this answer.
